# Get the Status Text from a http Service - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have a service which sends a POST request to a server:

```
addPerson(person:PersonDTO) :Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.urlBase + 'Persons', person);
}
```

I subscribe to the service in a component:

```
this.valueService.addPerson(person).subscribe((data) => {
   this.responseCode = data.statusText;
   console.log(this.responseCode)
});
```

I would like to print the response Code on the console. The problem is when there is an error the code stops before it comes to the `console.log`. And if there is no error `undefined` is displayed on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome here!

By default, the response is limited to the response body from your API.
To get additional info like the status, you need to add an `observe` option with your request:

```
addPerson(person:PersonDTO) :Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.urlBase + 'Persons', person, {observe: 'response'});
}
```

Basic subscription like yours means you are only dealing with the `next` use case.
To deal with error, you need another callback for errors:

```
this.valueService.addPerson(person).subscribe(
  (data) => {
   this.responseCode = data.statusText;
   console.log(this.responseCode)
  },
  (error) => console.error(error)
);
```

Comment: add error callback code as well. it was mentioned in the question as well.

Comment: Right @VimalPatel, thanks!

Comment: Now I have still the problem that if there is an error in the request it still does not get displayed

Comment: can you share the error from the network tab of your browser?